# How to set background to particular selceted Text from textarea into div?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add background color to particular selected text from Text area into div?

```
var elem=document.getElementById("askQuestionDescription");
var start=elem.value.substring(0,elem.selectionStart);    
var selection = elem.value.substring(elem.selectionStart,elem.selectionEnd);
var end=elem.value.substring(elem.selectionEnd,elem.length);
//   alert(start + ","+selection+","+end);
document.getElementById("askQuestionCodePreview").innerHTML=start+selection+end;
```

I want to set background on selection portion only.

Comment: show your html please. also creating a jsfiddle.net would be helpful. also can you confirm the following: You have an element, let's say a <div> with a text: "Just some text". You want to have different background colors inside the div for each word or how do I have to understand this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use this to change the background color of the selected text?

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selection.html

```
#askQuestionDescription::selection {
    background:red;
    color:white;
}

#askQuestionDescription::-moz-selection {
    background:red;
    color:white;
}

#askQuestionDescription::-webkit-selection {
    background:red;
    color:white;
}
```